# Handling connection refused from curb(-fu) call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curb

How can I deal with

```
Curl::Easy.http_get("dev-server.example.com")
Curl::Err::ConnectionFailedError: Curl::Err::ConnectionFailedError
```

from a curb or curb-fu call? Our dev servers are up and down so I need to be able to handle this better than getting an exception, the documentation seems very light.

Answer (score 0):

I came across rescue which gave me what I needed

```
Curl::Easy.http_get("dev-server.example.com") rescue <some action>
```